# How to create a shared session for a web app using react native

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I am trying to create an app where you have one device that starts the session and generates a code for others to join. once the app has generated the code, other devices can go to the the website and join the session using the code that was generated by the initial user.

An example of this would be the quiz game Kahoot. Someone creates a game and shares a code for others to join.

Is there a name for this that I can do some research into how it works as I cant seem to figure out where to start.

If not how would I go about creating this "Shared session" in react?

im not even sure id 'Shared session' is the right name

Answer (score 0):

I'm stuck with the same problem. So far, [this article](https://medium.com/@ktamura_74189/how-to-build-a-real-time-multiplayer-game-using-only-firebase-as-a-backend-b5bb805c6543) has been the most helpful.

You can also check out Socket.io as they support real-time messaging, but I believe you can use it for other things too.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).